# How to Compare between 2D String Array elements to find the repeated elements?

Tags: c, arrays, string, 2d

So, I have this coursework where we've been asked to find the repeated words in a string and display the repeated words and how many times they're repeated.

I had the idea of extracting the words and putting every word as a string in a 2D string Array and then comparing each element with the whole 2D array and in the case of repetition, the word is then displayed with the number of repetitions.

I was able to achieve the first part of extracting the words and putting them into a 2D string array. However, I'm stuck from there and not sure how to compare each element with the string.

your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Please format your code properly first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For comparison of the strings you can use the logic that :
There can be two loops nested , The outer loop will be from i=0 to number of words , inner from j=i+1 to number of words (In reference to rows of two-d array now the rows can be compared ).
Now as soon as duplicate is encountered it will be made 0 to avoid again and again check and count will be increased.After this while printing or performing any operation it will be checked that whether the count is more than 1 and also the word itself is not 0.

```
for(int i=0;i<n;++i){
        count = 1;

    for(int j=i+1;j<n;++j){

        if(word[i]==word[j]){
        ++count;     word[j]="0"; // this is to avoid recounting duplicate word

         }
     }                           // end of inner for loop

        if(count>1 && word[i]!=0){
        printf("Duplicate word is %s",word[i]);   //or any other work
        }
} // end of outer for loop
```

Comment: Thanks for the help :)  your method worked with some minor changes for the word[j]="0", I changed it to words[j][0]='\0'; and it worked !